# Correlation between two variables over time

Tags: time-series, correlation, cross-correlation

I have 5 individuals. I measure variable X and Y of each one of them over time (on 5 different time points). I want to find out if there are any correlations between X and Y over time and show the same trend for all 5 individuals.

The data looks like this (just an example, not my real data):

```
time 1:
X              Y
10            10        #individual 1
20            30        #individual 2
30            50        #individual 3
40            55        #individual 4
10            20        #individual 5

time 2:
X             Y         
2             6         #individual 1     
3             8         #individual 2
7             11        #individual 3
10            14        #individual 4
11            14        #individual 5
... e.t.c.
```

**Which statistical analysis should I use to test if X and Y (and that X and Y correlates) show the same trends for all 5 individuals over time?**

Comment: Do you expect the measures to be correlated within an individual? Do you expect the measures to be correlated across time?

Comment: Both. I expect that a correlation of X and Y can bee seen in each individual and on each time point.

Comment: To investigate the within individual dependence, multilevel/hierarchical models would be appropriate. To investigate the temporal dependence, a test of autocorrelation (time series) would be appropriate. Ideally your analysis would take both forms of dependence into consideration.

Comment: Start with plotting the data!

Comment: This is a 7 years old question, do you think I still work or have this data available?